# What is the difference between a null array and an empty array?

Tags: java, arrays

If the individual elements of an int array are not initialized, what is stored in them by default? I apparently found that there is something like an empty array or a null array. What is the difference, and which one applies to my first question?

Comment: You can have a zero-length array -- contains no elements.  You can have a null array reference -- the reference is null, meaning that no array actually exists.  You can have an array with elements that are all set to null -- this is the default for an array of references when it's initially created.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Technically speaking, there's no such thing as a *null array*; but since arrays are objects, array types are reference types (that is: array variables just hold *references* to arrays), and this means that an array variable can be `null` rather than actually pointing to an array:

```
int[] notAnArray = null;
```

An *empty* array is an array of length zero; it has no elements:

```
int[] emptyArray = new int[0];
```

(and can *never* have elements, because an array's length never changes after it's created).

When you create a *non*-empty array without specifying values for its elements, they default to zero-like values — `0` for an integer array, `null` for an array of an object type, etc.; so, this:

```
int[] arrayOfThreeZeroes = new int[3];
```

is the same as this:

```
int[] arrayOfThreeZeroes = { 0, 0, 0 };
```

(though these values can be re-assigned afterward; the array's length cannot change, but its elements can change).

Comment: And default value is false for a boolean array

Answer (score 2):

An array has its members initialized to their default values. For `int` the default is 0. For an `Object` it's `null`. A `null` array is a [`null` Array Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#d5e23921) (since arrays are reference types in Java).

[JLS-4.12.5 Initial Values of Variables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5) says in part

> For type int, the default value is zero, that is, 0.

and

> For all reference types (§4.3), the default value is null.

Comment: @Quantitative Correct. And for an `Integer[]`, but a `double[]` would default to 0 (being a primitive type).

Comment: The index 0 in `int[] a = new int[0]` has nothing to do with default values

Comment: @ThomasWeller `int[] a = new int[1];` has a default value at index `0`. In fact, any array length greater than `0` has a default value at index `0`.

Answer (score 1):

By default java initialized the array according to type declared. It is int then it is initialized to 0. If it is of type object like array of object then it is initialized to null.

Answer (score 0):

> If the individual elements of an int array are not initialized, what is stored in them by default?

`0`

empty array is array with 0 elements

I haven't heard about `null` array but it is probably an array with non zero element reference which are `null`